# SIM800C GSM Module with USB to TTL Serial CH340 Module

Tags: serial, uart, gsm, voltage

I'm planning to use this instead of connecting the pins of the GSM module to the pins of the RPi3B. Since the voltage for the TxD and RxD pins of the SIM800C is 5V and the TxD and RxD pins of the RPi3B is 3V, I will need resistors so I will not fry the RPi3B. But if I will use USB to TTL, are there still things I need to worry about? or the USB to TTL removes all my problems and hassle.

Comment: you have to worry about providing adequate power to the SIM800C

Comment: The USB to TTL supports both 5V and 3V

Comment: i did not say `voltage` ... i said `power` ... that means that the power supply has to provide sufficient `current`  without a drop in the output voltage

Comment: I see. I thought the USB will be the one to provide the power.